# SignUp con Facebook me retorna solo el nombre y el id

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil y debo aplicar login con facebook, vi tutoriales y todo y al final estoy a punto de lograrlo, pero debo mandar los datos por retrofit a un webservice, a la hora de solicitar los datos de "first_name", "last_name", "email" y "picture" me dice que no retorna nada asi que decidi hacer un Log.e de el objeto que me retorna el servicio de facebook y me di cuenta que solo me retorna name y id, luego vi en otro proyecto de referencia y si retorna todo, no se que puede ser.

Acceso a la informacion: (solo he puesto name porque es el que me retorna pero ahi deben estar first_name y tal).

```
private void loadUserProfile (final AccessToken accessToken)
{
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                String name = object.getString("name");
                //String fecha = object.getString("birthday");
                Log.e("entro","entro "+object);
                Log.e("entro","entro "+ name);
                Log.e("entro","entro "+ accessToken.getToken());

                //postFacebook(email,name,last_name,newAccessToken.getToken());
                //Log.e("entro","entro "+ fecha);
                //postRegistro(email,name +" "+ last_name,"",""+accessToken.getToken(),"1",""+accessToken.getToken());
                // displayName.setText(name);
                // emailID.setText(email);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("field", "id,name,email,picture.width(200),first_name,last_name");
    request.setParameters(parameters);

    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Este es el funcionamiento del boton de login de facebook:

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Log.e("Access Token:", "a: "+accessToken.getToken());
            loadUserProfile(accessToken);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: tienes esto?  loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL)); esta es la documentacion de fb https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

Comment: Si, si lo tengo